# Yii2 authentication based on record level

Tags: activerecord, yii2, rbac

Within yii2 I need some RBAC access control also on record level. As a yii2 beginner I'm searching for the best point to enter the logic but struggle through the documents.

Example:

- A table *Children* mentions a *child*, besides lots of other *children*.
- A child usually has *two parents* in table *Parents*.
- Besides other access control with yii2-admin/user these two parents can view and manipulate the record of their **own** child/ren but not others.
- the logged in user is a parent.

Example table *Children*:

```
|id|name|age|
|1|Max|10|
|2|Moritz|11|
|3|Lena|8|
...
```

Example table *Parents*:

```
|id|relation|name|
|1|mother|Anna|
|2|father|Paul|
|3|mother|Lisa|
...
```

Example table *Xref* (Relation to *Children* and *Parents*):

```
|child_id|parent_id|
|1|1|
|1|2|
|2|3|
|3|1|
|3|2|
...
```

I think the activeRecord class *Children* would be the the right place for a behaviour like that, right?
Does someone have an example code to point me to the right direction for an efficient code,
where Paul and Anna could modify the record for 'Max' but not for 'Moritz'?

Comment: It is generaly considered poor design to use RBAC on a record layer. In your case you should probably have an `ActiveRecord` method that takes a user `id` as a param and returns the children. 
RBAC level filtering (whether you can write/view) should be on nthe controller level.

Comment: I agree, and thanks for the tip. As a beginner in yii (not a beginner in programming) I'd like to ask for a code fragment as example to get in the shoes. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

I hardly ever use relational DBs with Yii2 but I will illustrate what I meant as best as possible:

I'm going to illustrate the Parent Class as the child will be roughly similar (appart from the relationship direction):

```
class ParentModel extends ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return string the name of the table associated with this ActiveRecord class.
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'Parents';
    }

    public function getChildren()
    {
        // ParentModel has_many ChildModel via Xref.child_id -> id
        return $this->hasMany(ChildModel::className(), ['id' => 'child_id'])
            ->viaTable('Xref', ['parent_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

With this you can get all children by using (for example):

```
$user = ParentModel::findOne($userID);
$children = $user->children;
```

You can then use all RBAC functionalities to make sure you users can't access an edit form action/view. Or use RBAC [rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#using-rules) to make sure only the appropriate content is being handled.
Or you could write your own checks to make sure (for example) that the children being handled really belong to the Parent accessing the controller action. (by say... comparing the user's children to the ones being handled, though depending on your structure this could be handled by RBAC Rules)

But regardless of the actions, that logic should remain on the controller layer. On some very rare occasions you might have to put access right logic in your models but the models should have that logic separated and not related to the RBAC system. I've personally had this issue with graph traversal logic which is on an ActiveQuery level. But that's another issue in it's own right.